# Host container returns error: "Expression has changed after it was checked" when checking the property of @viewChildren in Angular2

Tags: templates, angular, typescript, expression

I'm dealing with an error when I try to check the "valid" property of forms in child components via `@viewchildren` in the container HTML template.  I realize this error is caused by timing, strangly the error occurs when I enable prod mode.  The relevant documentation has a timer function, but I'm just not sure how that helps.  I have looked at several articles here, but nothing has sunk in yet.

I set up the view children here:

```
@ViewChildren(AddressComponent) addressComponents: QueryList<AddressComponent>"
```

Here is ngAfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log("this is ", this)
 this.addressComponents.toArray().forEach((address)=> {
 if(address.addressType == "shipper"){
   this.shipperForm = address.addressForm
  }
  else if(address.addressType == "recipient"){
    this.recipForm = address.addressForm
 }
 })
}
```

And the relevant template:
..`[disabled] = "!shipperForm.valid"`...causes the error.

The relevant error returned is:

> ...caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous
>   value:...

The entire class:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core';
import {AddressComponent} from '../address'
import {Shipment} from '../../containershipping/shared/shipment'
import any = jasmine.any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wide-address',
  templateUrl: './wide-address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['wide-address.component.scss']
})
export class WideAddressComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  addressForm: any;
  public addressTypes: any = [
    'shipper', 'recipient'
  ]
  public shipperForm:any;
  public recipForm:any;

  @ViewChildren(AddressComponent) addressComponents: QueryList<AddressComponent>
  private shippperComponent: AddressComponent;
  @ViewChild(AddressComponent)
  private recipComponent: AddressComponent;
  @Input() addressType: string;
  @Input() addresses: any;
  @Input() shipment: Shipment;
  @Input() useInternalButton:boolean;
  public showButton:boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("this is ", this)
    console.log("view children is ", this.addressComponents)
    //this.addressComponents.changes.subscribe(changes => console.log('changes are ', changes));
     this.addressComponents.toArray().forEach((address)=> {

     if(address.addressType == "shipper"){
       this.shipperForm = address.addressForm
      }
      else if(address.addressType == "recipient"){
        this.recipForm = address.addressForm
     }
     }
    )
  }

  updateShipmentObject() {
    this.addressComponents.toArray().forEach((address)=> {
        this.syncFieldsWithObject(address);
      }
    );
    this.shipment.showShippingSummary = true;
  }

  syncFieldsWithObject(component?: AddressComponent) {
    if (component.addressType == "shipper") {
      let shipAd = component.addressForm.controls;
      this.shipment.shipper = {};
      let shipAdObj = this.shipment.shipper
      shipAdObj.name = shipAd['name'].value;
      shipAdObj.address1 = shipAd['address1'].value;
      shipAdObj.address2 = shipAd['address2'].value;
      shipAdObj.city = shipAd['city'].value;
      shipAdObj.state = shipAd['state'].value;
      shipAdObj.country = shipAd['country'].value;
      shipAdObj.zip = shipAd['zip'].value;
      shipAdObj.phone = shipAd['phone'].value;
      shipAdObj.email = shipAd['email'].value;
    } else if (component.addressType == "recipient") {
      let recipAd = component.addressForm.controls;
      this.shipment.recipient = {};
      let recipAdObj = this.shipment.recipient;
      recipAdObj.name = recipAd['name'].value;
      recipAdObj.address1 = recipAd['address1'].value;
      recipAdObj.address2 = recipAd['address2'].value;
      recipAdObj.city = recipAd['city'].value;
      recipAdObj.state = recipAd['state'].value;
      recipAdObj.country = recipAd['country'].value;
      recipAdObj.zip = recipAd['zip'].value;
      recipAdObj.phone = recipAd['phone'].value;
      recipAdObj.email = recipAd['email'].value;
    }

  }
}
```

and the html template:

```
<div id="address_paymt_info">
  <div class="table_replace table_page" >
    <div class="row small-12 columns acsPageTitle">
      Contact Information
    </div>
    <div class="sideByside">
      <app-address #shipperComp [addressType]="'shipper'"></app-address>
      <app-address #recipientComp [addressType]="'recipient'"></app-address>
    </div>
  </div>



  <button (click)="updateShipmentObject()" class="button-primary"  >Get Shipment Information  (not enabled by default)</button>

    <input type="button" value="Continue" class="button-primary" [disabled] = "!shipperForm.valid" > &nbsp; - this shouldn't be enabled by default

{{shipperForm}}

</div>
```

Comment: It's being called from a component that contains two sub-components.  Would it be helpful to add the entire class?

Comment: I found one work around.  Add a hash identifier to the subcomponent, and then use that as the basis for the property expression.

`<app-address #shipperComp [addressType]="'shipper'"</app-address>
{{shipperComp.addressForm.valid }}`

then in the template in the element you want to target:
 `[disabled]="!shipperComp.addressForm.valid || !recipientComp.addressForm.valid"`